# Create an array from others

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, angular, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make an array from a few arrays.

For example **:**

```
array1= ['Joe','James','Carl','Angel','Jimmy',];
array2= ['22','11','29','43','56',];
array3= ['red','blue','orange','brown','yellow',];
```

I need to create a new array pushing by index.
What I'm trying to do is something like this **:**

```
newArray=['Joe22red','james11blue','Carl29orange','Angel43brown','Jimmy56yellow']
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to find out the result

```js
const array1= ['Joe','James','Carl','Angel','Jimmy',];
const array2= ['22','11','29','43','56',];
const array3= ['red','blue','orange','brown','yellow',];

const result = array1.map(
  (item, index) => `${item}${array2[index]}${array3[index]}`
)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks!
¿And if we don´t know how many arrays are?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```js
array1= ['Joe','James','Carl','Angel','Jimmy'];
array2= ['22','11','29','43','56'];
array3= ['red','blue','orange','brown','yellow'];
newArray = []
for (let i =0; i<Math.max(array1.length, array2.length, array3.length); i++) {
    newArray.push(`${array1[i]}${array2[i]}${array3[i]}`)
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

*And if we don´t know how many arrays are?* Here is solution

```js
const array1= ['Joe','James','Carl','Angel','Jimmy',];
const array2= ['22','11','29','43','56',];
const array3= ['red','blue','orange','brown','yellow',];

const data = [array1, array2, array3];

const result = data[0].map((_, index) => data.map((arr) => arr[index]).join(''));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an approach that consider using [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) method. It can receive up to four parameters from which the first three can be used.

A one liner solution that works with three arrays with the same lenght:

```js
array1=["Joe","James","Carl","Angel","Jimmy"],array2=["22","11","29","43","56"],array3=["red","blue","orange","brown","yellow"];

console.log(
array1.reduceRight((acc,curr,i) => [curr + array2[i] + array3[i],  ...acc], [])
)
```